# HttpContext.Current.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>() is null in asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get the current culture from a user class in ASP.NET Core 1.1.

I have the following under `ConfigureServices` in *Startup.cs*:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("fil-PH")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

I have the following under `Configure` in *Startup.cs*:

```cs
IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
Extensions.Context.Configure(httpContextAccessor);

IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>  localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);
```

I have the following user class:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Framework.Extensions
{
    public class Context
    {
        public HttpContext Current { get; set; }
        public Uri AbsoluteUri { get; set; }
        public string AbsolutePath { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

        private static IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
        public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public Context()
        {
            Current = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            AbsoluteUri = GetAbsoluteUri();
            AbsolutePath = GetAbsoluteUri().AbsolutePath;
            Url = GetAbsoluteUri().ToString();
            Culture = GetCultureInfo();
        }

        private Uri GetAbsoluteUri()
        {
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
            uriBuilder.Scheme = Current.Request.Scheme;
            uriBuilder.Host = Current.Request.Host.Host.ToString();
            if (Current.Request.Host.Port != null)
            {
                uriBuilder.Port = Current.Request.Host.Port ?? default(int);
            }
            uriBuilder.Path = Current.Request.Path.ToString();
            uriBuilder.Query = Current.Request.QueryString.ToString();
            Uri absoluteUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
            return uriBuilder.Uri;
        }

        private CultureInfo GetCultureInfo() {
            IFeatureCollection requestFeatures = Current.Features; /* POPULATED */
            RequestCultureFeature requestCultureFeature = requestFeatures.Get<RequestCultureFeature>(); /* NULL */
            RequestCulture requestCulture = requestCultureFeature.RequestCulture;
            return requestCulture.Culture;
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the `GetCultureInfo()` method, **`Current` appears to be correctly populated** with info as I can see things like the host and port, etc.   `Features` is also populated - at least not null.   But calling `Get<RequestCultureFeature>()` on the Features is null?

Any ideas at why this would be empty, and how to fix it?

The reason I am trying to access it is to get the CurrentUICulture.

Comment: What happens if you use: `requestFeatures.Get<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>()`? Or I think you should be injecting `IOptions` into your controller and accessing the property on it, isn't it?

Comment: @SivaGopal using `requestFeatures.Get<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>()` is null too.

Comment: Then did you try injecting `IOptions` into controller and accessing the property?

Comment: It isn't in a Controller.   As stated, it is in a user class (with the full code of the user class shown above).  Or maybe, I am misunderstanding your response?

Comment: No I misunderstood it being controller. So in your case still I guess you can create a parameterized constructor and so that `Dependency Injection` container should still be able to inject instance for your `IOptions`

Comment: @SivaGopal If you could "Answer" the question, I will award it as the correct answer.

Comment: I think the reason Get<RequestCultureFeature>() is null is because you need to use Get<IRequestCultureFeature>() the interface instead of the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a parameterized constructor in `Context` class with `IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>` and once you register the `RequestLocalizationOptions` for Dependency Injection Service inside `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs`, framework will provide the registered instance into the `Context` class.

As you suggested concluding our comments here in case if it would be useful for someone else as well.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you aren't registering the `RequestLocalizationMiddleware` middleware:

`app.UseRequestLocalization()` is the extension method that should add the middleware, which will set the feature for you.

Comment: That was in the OP's listing.

Answer (score 4):

if  your UseRequestLocalization() is coming after the call for UseMvc()
try to  Call UseRequestLocalization() before UseMvc() .
and use the following code

```
var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me with a razor pages site, once I moved the UseRequestLocalization() call in front of `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });`  Thanks for sharing!